# Three ggplots in a 2x2 grid

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Is it possible to set (with `par(mfrow=())` or something else) a multiple plot panel for 3 ggplot objects, where one takes whole row and the other two are placed in second row?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this using arrangeGrob / grid.arrange from gridExtra.
See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html)
To do this for your example, you'd do

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
g1 <- qplot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
g2 <- qplot(rpois(100, 10), geom = "histogram")
g3 <- qplot(rnorm(10))
my_plots <- list(g1, g2, g3)
my_layout <- rbind(c(1, 1), c(2, 3))
grid.arrange(grobs = my_plots, layout_matrix = my_layout)
```

Comment: Russ, any idea why I get `Error in t:b : NA/NaN argument` error when following you code? Plots are stored in `my_plots <- c(g1, g2, g3)`, each one displays correctly when called in console.

Comment: Yep. You didn't make a list of plots, you tried to make a vector of plots. Use `my_plots <- list(g1, g2, g3)` and try again.

Comment: Interesting.  I've no idea at all. I'll edit for a more specific image.

Comment: No, it's all good now. list(a,b,c) did the trick. I was to quick in commenting. Your solution does what I was looking for and I already accepted it. Thanks