# Arranging table grobs using gridExtra

Tags: r, gridextra

```
     tab1 <- tableGrob(df1)        
     tab2 <- tableGrob(df2)
     tab3 <- tableGrob(df3)
     lay <- rbind(c(1,1),
                  c(1,2))

      pdf("file.pdf", height = 25, width = 13)
      grid.arrange(grobs = list(tab1, tab2, tab3), layout_matrix = lay)
      dev.off()
```

I'm getting the following error:
Error in t:b : NA/NaN argument

Comment: The layout is wrong? Try `lay <- rbind(c(1,1), c(2,3))`, you have 3 tabs, top will be for tab1 and bottom will be tab2 and tab3.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47591858/680068